# Не удается подключить библиотеку PHPWORD для работы с doc/docx документами. Что я неправильно делаю?

Tags: php, composer, ms-word, phpword, зависимости

Установил через консоль OpenServer библиотеку PHPWord по инструкции разработчика https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord#installation

Composer ошибку не показал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но библиотека явно установилась некорректно, потому что при запуске скрипта подключение библиотеки выдает ошибку..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму, в чем ошибка.. Смотрю папки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если открывать файл composer.phar, который относится к библиотеке PHPWORD, в нем следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы неверно указываете путь до файла `autoload.php`

Comment: Вернее не там запустили Composer и имеете файл composer.json. Поместите его внутрь директории localhost, в консоли войдите в неё и оттуда запускайте composer. Папка vendor также должна находиться в localhost. Либо переместите папку с файлом внутрь localhost.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Оба совета очень помогли.. Заработало! Только я не понимаю.. Я установил composer глобально (один из видов установки при котором не надо в каждой папке). Ранее с его помощью библиотеки корректно устанавливались.. Почему же для PHPWORD установка оказалась некорректно..?